# customize Android Facebook Login button

Tags: android, android-facebook

I want to customize the look of the Facebook login button which we get along with the Facebook sdk for android (facebook-android-sdk-3.0.1). I want a simple android button which has title "Login via Facebook". I could not find any documentation regarding that.

So if any one knows on how to do it in a simple way, please tell me or direct me on how to do it.

Comment: I have never used the facebook sdk ... but if their is an image file assosciated with the login button you can just modify that ... if not completely ignore my comment

Comment: its just not an image file associated button. its got lot of functionality associated with it for eg:it changes its text based on wether the user is logged in or not

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You can use styles for modifiy the login button like this

```
<style name="FacebookLoginButton">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/smallTxtSize</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/facebook_signin_btn</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_horizontal</item>
</style>
```

and in layout

```
<com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
        xmlns:fb="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/loginFacebookButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        fb:login_text="@string/loginFacebookButton"
        fb:logout_text=""
        style="@style/FacebookLoginButton"/>
```

Comment: Hi @Filsh, Is there any official documentation about these properties? I didnt find it.

Comment: It doesn't work anymore. Gradle halts with an error when building. Use LoginManager and a standard Button.

Answer (score 175):

In order to have completely custom facebook login button without using `com.facebook.widget.LoginButton`.

According to facebook sdk 4.x,

There new concept of login as from facebook

> [LoginManager and AccessToken](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/v2.3) - These new classes perform Facebook
>   Login

So, Now you can access Facebook authentication without Facebook login button as

*layout.xml*

```
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_fb_login"
            .../>
```

*MainActivity.java*

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
                new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        Log.d("Success", "Login");

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Cancel", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btn_fb_login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_fb_login);

        btn_fb_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                  LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(MainActivity.this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends"));
            }
        });

    }

@Override 
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); 
}
```

Comment: Error : logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends"));

Can not resolve symbol

Comment: @Ilario, Thanks for your advise. now edited my answer

Comment: Seriously, the only ansewr that worked for me using the v2.4 of the sdk.

Comment: Small edit: 

call  logInWithReadPermissions with first parameter outer variable final Fragment fr = this;

Comment: @ShaktisinhJadeja this refers to OnClickListener context. logInWithReadPermissions needs an activity or fragment as first parameter. So put YourActivityName.this or YourFragmentName.this instead.

Comment: This answer is working fine.Can anyone tell me after login how to logout from facebook in android app?

Comment: @BABUK you can call LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();

Comment: THIS ANSWER HAS A MEMORY LEAK!!
all the code for registerCallback() should be unregistered or the activity will leak. I would suggest moving this code into onStart() and adding following code in onStop:         LoginManager.getInstance().unregisterCallback(callbackManager)

Comment: no need to call `FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());` anymore

Comment: it's deprecated method

Answer (score 38):

The best way I have found to do this, if you want to fully customize the button is to create a button, or any View you want (in my case it was a `LinearLayout`) and set an `OnClickListener` to that view, and call the following in the onClick event:

```
com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton btn = new LoginButton(this);
btn.performClick();
```

Comment: It works. But unnecessary. There is no need to use a Facebook Login Button and fake its click. Use the LoginManager instead.

Comment: Vitor is right, much easier to customise your own button and use Login manager

Answer (score 19):

1. Create custom facebook button and change visability on native facebook button:

   ```
   <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:orientation="vertical">

       <Button
               android:id="@+id/facebookView"
               android:layout_width="300dp"
               android:layout_height="48dp"
               android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
               android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
               android:background="@drawable/btn_frame"
               android:gravity="center"
               android:text="@string/Sign_in_facebook_button"
               android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />

       <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
               android:id="@+id/facebookButton"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:visibility="invisible"
               android:layout_marginBottom="12dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
   ```
2. Add listener to your fake button and simulate click:

   ```
   facebookView.setOnClickListener(this);
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
       if (v.getId() == R.id.facebookView){
          facebookButton.performClick();
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 16):

You can modifiy the login button like this

```
<com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
            xmlns:fb="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/login_button"
            android:layout_width="249dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/login_desc"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            fb:login_text=""
            fb:logout_text="" />
```

And in code I defined the background resource :

```
final LoginButton button = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.facebook);
```

Comment: Hey @RINK, the `fb:login_text` and `fb:logout_text` throw an error when trying to run.  Here is the error : `Error parsing XML: unbound prefix`.  Are you sure that is the proper syntax?

Comment: Obviously late, but @toobsco42 - make sure you have the xmlns:fb defined (to http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto), either in the button as shown here, or at the top level of your layout file.

Comment: facebook SDK 3.0 or above its  facebook:login_text=""
            facebook:logout_text=""

Comment: @RINK write this also then you will not get this error

xmlns:fb="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

Comment: Button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,0,0,0); , write this too [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16496738/is-it-possible-to-change-facebook-login-button-image-in-facebook-android-sdk3)

Answer (score 9):

In newer Facebook SDK, the login and logout text name is :

```
 <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
 xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 facebook:com_facebook_login_text=""
 facebook:com_facebook_logout_text=""/>
```

Comment: It works, how did you figure out? digging into SDK code?

Answer (score 5):

```
//call Facebook onclick on your customized button on click by the following

FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
                new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        Log.d("Success", "Login");

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Cancel", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button mycustomizeedbutton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.mycustomizeedbutton);

        mycustomizeedbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                  LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends"));
            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 <com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
            android:id="@+id/login_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            facebook:confirm_logout="false"
            facebook:fetch_user_info="true"
            android:text="testing 123"
            facebook:login_text=""
            facebook:logout_text=""
            />
```

This worked for me. To change the facebook login button text.

Answer (score 2):

Customize ***com.facebook.widget.LoginButton***

*step:1* Creating a ***Framelayout.***

*step:2*  To set ***com.facebook.widget.LoginButton***

*step:3*  To set **Textview** with customizable.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/fbLogin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        facebook:confirm_logout="false"
        facebook:fetch_user_info="true"
        facebook:login_text=""
        facebook:logout_text="" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_radio_setting_login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/drawable_radio_setting_loginbtn"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
</FrameLayout>
```

**MUST REMEMBER**

> 1> com.facebook.widget.LoginButton & TextView ***Height/Width Same***
>
> 2> ***1st declate*** com.facebook.widget.LoginButton ***then***
>   TextView
>
> 3> To perform login/logout using ***TextView's Click-Listener***

Answer (score 2):

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/FrameLayout1"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="132dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/logbu">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fb"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/fb"
        android:onClick="onClickFacebookButton"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

    <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton

        android:alpha="0"  <!--***SOLUTION***-->
        android:id="@+id/buttonFacebookLogin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="45sp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:com_facebook_login_text="Log in with Facebook" />

</FrameLayout>
```

The easiest way to customize the integrated facebook button for both java and kotlin

Comment: Ingenious answer

Answer (score 1):

### Its a trick not a proper method.

- Create a Relative layout.
- Define your facebook_botton.
- Also define your custom design button.
- Overlap them.

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp">
    <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/login_button"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp" />
    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llfbSignup"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/facebook"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:src="@drawable/facbk"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
    <View
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/fullGray"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
    <com.yadav.bookedup.fonts.GoutamBold
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="Sign Up via Facebook"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple. Add a button in the layout file like

```
<Button
   android:layout_width="200dp"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="Login with facebook"
   android:textColor="#ffff"
   android:layout_gravity="center"
   android:textStyle="bold"
   android:onClick="fbLogin"
   android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>
```

And in the onClick place the LoginManager's registercallback() method Becuse the this method automatically executes.

```
  public void fbLogin(View view)
{
    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("user_photos", "email", "public_profile", "user_posts" , "AccessToken"));
    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));
    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
            new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult)
                {
                    // App code
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel()
                {
                    // App code
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException exception)
                {
                    // App code
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Proper and Cleanest way**

After checking the answers below, it seems that they're kind of hacks that rely on editing the login button view to make it more suitable for your need.

[image: Demo image]

Being in the same position, I've succeeded to customize the facebook login button efficiently.

```
<mehdi.sakout.fancybuttons.FancyButton
   android:id="@+id/facebook_login"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="45dp"
   android:paddingLeft="10dp"
   android:paddingRight="10dp"
   app:fb_radius="2dp"
   app:fb_iconPosition="left"
   app:fb_fontIconSize="20sp"
   app:fb_iconPaddingRight="10dp"
   app:fb_textSize="16sp"
   app:fb_text="Facebook Connect"
   app:fb_textColor="#ffffff"
   app:fb_defaultColor="#39579B"
   app:fb_focusColor="#6183d2"
   app:fb_fontIconResource="&#xf230;"
   android:layout_centerVertical="true"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

and implement the onClickListener like so

```
FacebookLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
      if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null){
         mLoginManager.logOut();
      } else {
         mAccessTokenTracker.startTracking();
         mLoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(MainActivity.this,              Arrays.asList("public_profile"));
      }
   }
});
```

You could find the whole source code on: http://medyo.github.io/customize-the-android-facebook-login-on-android

Comment: Need to alter official button, not to add your own button