# Is it possible to change Facebook login button image in Facebook Android SDK3?

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

Facebook Android sdk  has a `com.facebook.widget.LoginButton`

I want to put my own image for the Login button. Is it possible ?

So far i've tried adding `android:src="@drawable/facebook"` to the layout file as an attribute to the button element with no luck

Answer (score 78, accepted):

I ended up overriding the text to be empty string and then defining the `setBackgroundResource` of the button to my image (didn't need the dynamic login/logout text functionality)

```
<com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
        xmlns:fb="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_width="249dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/login_desc"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        fb:login_text=""
        fb:logout_text="" />
```

And in code I defined the background resource :

```
final LoginButton button = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.facebook);
```

Kind of a workaround, but I preferred this over changing Facebook SDK code (although it's very straight forward as well) and worry about updating each time I update the their version.

Comment: Just curious: where did you even find the documentation/help about the `fb:login_text` and such XML attributes? It's exactly what I was looking for but have no idea how people stumbled upon it.

Comment: Facebook sdk is open source. Check its res/values/attrs.xml

Comment: add button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0); to remove that 'f' icon of Facebook.

Comment: @user3740085 on your view xml containing the fb widget, in the fb widget element (`<com.facebook.widget.LoginButton ... />`) add attribute `fb:logout_text="logout text"`

Comment: New updated facebook sdk in android-studio- i am getting no resource found error  fb:login_text=""
        fb:logout_text=""  build time same code but getting above 2 error

Comment: To changed text facebook:com_facebook_login_text="New text" https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook/res/values/attrs.xml

Answer (score 10):

yes if you want to change text and image both then write the below code.

```
authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
authButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon);
authButton.setText("Login");
authButton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, null, null);`
```

Answer (score 2):

An other way

```
loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.fb_login_button);
loginButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);




ImageView ivFbCustomButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_fb_custom_button);
ivFbCustomButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton btn = new com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton(FacebookActivity.this);
        btn.performClick();
    }
});
```

**Note:**

You have to write the code for two buttons in XML file. One is for default facebook button (We are hiding it at initial step). Second one is for custom button

Answer (score 0):

Create a drawable with name com_facebook_button_icon.xml add anything inside it FB login button will override as it uses as drawableleft.

For example:

```
<vector
android:height="25dp"
android:viewportHeight="1365.3333"
android:viewportWidth="1365.3333"
android:width="25dp"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:tintMode="multiply"
android:tint="@color/com_facebook_button_text_color"
>
<path
    android:fillAlpha="1"
    android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:fillType="nonZero"
    android:pathData="m1365.33,682.67c0,-377.03 -305.64,-682.67 -682.67,-682.67C305.64,-0 0,
        305.64 0,682.67 0,1023.41 249.64,1305.83 576,1357.04L576,880L402.67,880l0,
        -197.33l173.33,-0l0,-150.4c0,-171.09 101.92,-265.6 257.85,-265.6 74.69,-0 152.81,
        13.33 152.81,13.33L986.67,448L900.58,448C815.78,448 789.33,500.62 789.33,
        554.61L789.33,682.67L978.67,682.67L948.4,880L789.33,880L789.33,1357.04C1115.69,
        1305.83 1365.33,1023.41 1365.33,682.67"
    android:strokeColor="#00000000"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

just do this in your kotlin or java file

- facebookSignIn is button name

```
 binding.facebookSignIn.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,0,0,0)
```

or

- if you are not using binding then use findviewbyId and then

```
facebookSignIn.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,0,0,0)
```