# How to change the height of the 'Log in with Facebook' button?

Tags: android, facebook, android-xml, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.0

I already tried several answers I could find but none of them worked with the latest Facebook Android SDK version 4.0.

How can I change the layout height with the latest SDK?

Answer (score 179, accepted):

Just set paddingTop and paddingBottom. It works for me.

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/login_facebook_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"/>
```

Comment: How can we increase the size of the Facebook icon in the button?

Comment: I don't know why but when I set android:padding="16dp" it didn't work, only when I set each padding direction explicitly , thanks for the tip

Answer (score 30):

For `Facebook SDK v4.x` (*or rather than using separate xml style or programmatically*)

The `height` of button is decided by its `padding` and `textSize`.

So if you want to increase button size, do it something like this

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
facebook:com_facebook_login_text="Log in with Facebook"
android:id="@+id/login_button"
android:textSize="15sp"
android:paddingTop="15dp" <!--increase more until it matches ur requirement -->
android:paddingBottom="15dp">
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: The material design guidelines recommend using an 8dp rhythm. Also, `sp` should be used only for text sizes, not dimensions. Finally, `<!-- -->` comments cannot be enclosed inside an XML tag.

Comment: @PaulLammertsma ofcz we can't put comment tag in properties. The <!-- --> is for explanation purpose not the actual code.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to create a custom `LoginButton`.

You can just change the `LoginButton` parameters programmatically as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29479735/954811).