# Can't change the height of my Facebook login button (Android)

Tags: android, xml, facebook, android-layout, android-activity

I'm trying to change the dimensions of my Facebook login button - however I'm only able to change the width of the button and for some reason the height always stays the same.

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    facebook:com_facebook_login_text="Log in with Facebook"
    android:id="@+id/login_button"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
```

Any ideas why?

I have also tried putting the button in its own LinearLayout and setting both width and height to match_parent but again the height remains constant.

Grateful for any help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook SDK v4 LoginButton ignores XML customizations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29446879/facebook-sdk-v4-loginbutton-ignores-xml-customizations)

Comment: I don't have the same LoginButton class as him

Comment: @iLearnAndr0id Yes you do - `com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton`. Look beyond the first code block and you'll see...

Comment: set paddingTop and paddingBottom,http://stackoverflow.com/a/32403046/2562861

Answer (score 3):

For Facebook SDK v4.x (*or rather than using separate xml style*)

The height of button is decided by its padding and textSize.

So if you want to increase button size, do it something like this

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
facebook:com_facebook_login_text="Log in with Facebook"
android:id="@+id/login_button"

android:textSize="15sp"
android:paddingTop="15sp" <!--increase more until it matches ur requirement -->
android:paddingBottom="15sp">
```

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom button.
To do this, create a custom style in your style.xml :

```
<style name="CustomFbButton">
<item name="android:background">THE IMAGE OF FB BUTTON</item>
<item name="android:layout_height">300dp</item>
<item name="android:layout_width">65dp</item>
<item name="android:layout_marginTop">If you need</item>
<item name="android:layout_marginBottom">If you need</item>
<item name="android:layout_gravity">center_horizontal</item> </style>
```

Now you can put into your xml (of your activity (where the button is)) :

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
facebook:com_facebook_login_text="Log in with Facebook"
android:id="@+id/login_button"
style="@style/CustomFbButton/>
```

Comment: Hi. Can you give me an example of how I could write a custom style for a button with 300dp width and 65dp height? And how I could use it in my code?

Comment: I didn't know you could customise buttons this way - thanks. However, I still have the same problem :( Everything works apart from the height. I increased text size which increased the button height, but the logo stayed the same size (small). Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: I try just with that :
  <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:text="Login Facebook"
        android:id="@+id/btnFacebook" />

And that worked. So without any custom style...
May you have margin which block the size..

Answer (score 0):

Try this code using the code below. I used it and it worked for me.

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
facebook:com_facebook_login_text="Log in with Facebook"
android:id="@+id/login_button"
android:layout_width="240dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingTop="15dp"
android:paddingBottom="15dp"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
```