# how to remove only facebook logo on facebook login button

Tags: android, facebook

I want to totally remove logo of facebook on `com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton` i was tried `btnFacebook.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.applogo);` but its not working

please help me to remove logo

```
                         <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
                            xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                            android:id="@+id/btnFacebook"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_weight="6"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@color/facebookBlue"
                            android:paddingTop="15dp"
                            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                            facebook:com_facebook_login_text="\tSIGN IN WITH FACEBOOK"
                            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="15dp" />
```

In code it is looks like this :

[image]

And I want like this :

[image]

Comment: You can find more information about that here...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16496738/is-it-possible-to-change-facebook-login-button-image-in-facebook-android-sdk3

Comment: 14.4 of the platform policy tells you not to hide elements from social plugins...

Comment: [This question here might help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16314651/customize-android-facebook-login-button)

Comment: thank you all i will check it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to change Facebook login button image in Facebook Android SDK3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16496738/is-it-possible-to-change-facebook-login-button-image-in-facebook-android-sdk3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**the best way is
1-create new button call it x
2-customize background of this button
3-create a "`com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton`"  call it y
4-make this LoginButton's visibility = GONE
5-`performClick()` y on when button x `onClickListener()` **