# How to change the language of com.facebook.widget.LoginButton on Android

Tags: android, locale, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-3.14.x

How can I change the language which the `com.facebook.widget`'s use for display the labels?
I am using the `com.facebook.widget.LoginButton` and the system language of my Android device is set to german but however the `LoginButton` displays the text "Log in with Facebook" instead of "Mit Facebook anmelden". I also checked the Localize settings of my app on the Facebook developer page which is default german.

Comment: This might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16314651/customize-android-facebook-login-button

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It does not include German language localization.

In your layout, set the custom login_text attribute...

```
    <com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
        (usual attributes removed)
        loginView:login_text="Whatever text you want" />
```

Assuming you set the loginView namespace on your root element...

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:loginView="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    (usual attributes removed)... >
```

Following the same example to include logout text it will be:

```
<com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
        (usual attributes removed)
        loginView:login_text="Whatever text you want"
        loginView:logout_text="Your logout text" />
```

Comment: Thanks! Works =)
I also use the same for the logoutView.

Comment: Are there also attributes for setting the text of the logout dialog which is also completely in english? How are they called? I cannot find any references...

Comment: `AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource identifier found for attribute \u0027login_text\u0027 in package \u0027com.etutore.android\u0027","sources":[{"file":"/Users/cassio/Workspace/etutore-android-student/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_login.xml","position":{"startLine":51}}],"original":""}`

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.