# How to customize Facebook Login Button in Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk

I am having a customize FB sign-in thing needed in my android application. 
Below is the sample snapshot of the FB Login Button which I want.
[image]

**FacebookLoginXMLFile**

```
<com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
            xmlns:fb="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/authButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAlignment = "center"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:background="@drawable/emailbtn"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/facebook_small"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
            android:padding="5.75dp"
            android:paddingTop ="4dp"
            android:paddingRight="4dp"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            fb:login_text="@string/signinwithfacebook"
            fb:logout_text="@string/sign_out_from_facebook"
            android:longClickable="false"/>
```

But I am still getting Facebook's blue color in the background.

**PS:I have tried various suggestions from SO itself and none of them work for me**

Comment: when you add com.facebook.widget.LoginButton its automatically call its default blue button

Comment: try this way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16314651/customize-android-facebook-login-button

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I already try that link. It was not working for me

Comment: Send a blank email to me, i'll give you a sample.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use this xml for customize. Replace button with your customized button.

```html
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/FrameLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
            android:id="@+id/login_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fb"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#416BC1"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="FaceBook"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

Form more information check my answer,it is full step by step code for facebook login button customization.
[Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31327897/custom-facebook-login-button-android/31332928#31332928)

Comment: tried to run code snippet not showing output, seems not working in 2020.