# Android Custom facebook button, icon not loading properly

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-layout, android-activity

I create a custom facebook login button, but the icon on the button is not showing corretly. can you help me please

Login XML:

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/login_button"
            style="@style/ParseLoginUI.Button.ThirdPartyLogin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/com_parse_ui_small_vertical_spacing"
            android:background="@drawable/com_parse_ui_facebook_login_button_background_selector"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/com_parse_ui_facebook_login_logo"
            android:text="@string/com_parse_ui_facebook_login_button_label"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Style:

```
<style name="ParseLoginUI.Button.ThirdPartyLogin" parent="ParseLoginUI.Button">
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">16dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">24dp</item>
</style>


<style name="ParseLoginUI.Button" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">48dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/com_parse_ui_parse_login_button_background_selector</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/com_parse_ui_parse_login_display_text</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
</style>
```

Code:

```
loginButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        //loginButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.com_parse_ui_facebook_login_logo); //DONT WORK
        //loginButton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0,0,0); //DONT WORK
```

I want my button to look like this 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKxX3.png
[image]
originally its from the Parse sample

This is how its showing 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

No need to create extra drawable . Just call

```
<com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
android:id="@+id/authButtonFb"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

You will also need to add this to the Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:fb="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

For Details [Login with Facebook](http://kpbird.blogspot.in/2013/03/android-login-using-facebook-sdk-30.html) And [customize-android-facebook-login-button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16314651/customize-android-facebook-login-button)

If you use Android studio Then call this in your build.gradle

```
    dependencies { 
  compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
                  }
```

I hope it will helps you .

Answer (score 0):

instead of button use default facebook button(Please add facebook jar).it will give you same output as you want.

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
android:id="@+id/login_button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Using `facebook-android-sdk:3.19.0` dependency:

```
<com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/button_facebook_login"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/com_facebook_inverse_icon"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/com_facebook_inverse_icon"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" />
```

If you are using `facebook-android-sdk:4.20.0`, the drawable icon is named `com_facebook_button_login_logo`