# Facebook login button change height and width in Android Studio

Tags: android, facebook

I have integrate facebook sdk using https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started step by step .How to change login button height and width?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16314651/customize-android-facebook-login-button

Comment: In this link i have changed height width but not showing design

Answer (score 1):

Let's try a workaround: just define the paddings for the button.

```
   <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_facebook_login"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="16dp"
                android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        />
```

That works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook's new sdk doesn't allow you to change the height of the login button. Instead, I would create a custom button that does this for you.

Answer (score 0):

just add a style in your facebook login button

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/login_button"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    style="@style/FacebookLoginButton"
    />
```

And in your style write the below code:

```
<style name="FacebookLoginButton">
        <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingTop">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_horizontal</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: this only increases the height.. not width

Answer (score 0):

To change the height try adding padding both top and bottom

```
   <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/login_button"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"/>
```