# How to change Facebook LoginButton height atribute on Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

How can I change the height attribute in the LoginButton on Facebook SDK 4.x.x without editing the Facebook Class?

I already set the attribute in the xml file:

```
    <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        xmlns:fb="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/ac45LoginButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        fb:com_facebook_login_text="Entrar com Facebook"
        fb:com_facebook_logout_text="Sair"
        fb:com_facebook_confirm_logout="false"
        fb:com_facebook_tooltip_mode="never_display"/>
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible, you might want to check other ways [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16314651/customize-android-facebook-login-button)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try:

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
                android:id="@+id/fb_login_button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                android:paddingTop="15dp"/>
```