# facebook Login button customization

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

Using facebook sdk 4.6.0 i am trying to use facebook login integration in my android app.
com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton shows following button [image]

I want to change text from "Login with Facebook" to "FACEBOOK" only

I have tried almost all solutions provided previously, but none of them worked for me. Probable reason i could think of is that all previously answered question are for facebook sdk 3.0 which seems to fails for facebook sdk 4.6.0

I tried:

1. modifying LoginButton Class but it is locked
2. xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" using this schema in LoginButton and changing text using facbook:login_text="LOGIN",
   facebook:com_facebook_login_text="LOGIN" but both failed to work

This is my dependencies for facebook sdk
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'

This is my LoginButton xml

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/buttonRegisterFacebook"
    android:padding="10dp"
   />
```

Please suggest some way to change text and change fb logo image size

**Edit** : Now i understand why none of the previously stated method is working for me. My Facebook SDK files are locked

[image: LoginButton.java file is locked]

I tried unlocking by clicking on lock button at bottum right corner in android studio but nothing happens. Any suggestions how to unlock FB SDK files. My FB SDK version is 4.6.0

Comment: Plz see this if not already found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16314651/customize-android-facebook-login-button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching a lot, i found out for the recent Facebook SDK 4.6.0, inorder to only change FB Login Button text, add this to res/values/strings.xml

```
<string name="com_facebook_loginview_log_out_button">Your Logout Text</string>
<string name="com_facebook_loginview_log_in_button_long">Your Login Text</string>
```

However, if we want to have a FB Login button functionality in any random button

add following lines to ClickListener of random button ('buttonLogin' in my case )

```
buttonLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           LoginButton loginButton = new LoginButton(Login.this);
           AccessTokenTracker accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
               @Override
               protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldAccessToken, AccessToken newAccessToken) {
                   updateWithToken(newAccessToken);
               }
           };

           CallbackManager callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
           loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email"));
           loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, callback);
           loginButton.performClick();
}
```

I only required users public profile and email

updateWithToken() goes as

```
private void updateWithToken( AccessToken currentAccessToken ){
    if(currentAccessToken!=null){
        Log.v("MyApp", getClass().toString() + "updateWithToken:If(Token NonNull)");

        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(currentAccessToken, new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                Log.v("MyApp",getClass().toString() + response.toString());
                // Get facebook data from login
                try {
                    Log.v("MyApp", getClass().toString() + object.toString()); // contains data string
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.v("MyApp", getClass().toString() + "LoginJSON");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, Home.class); // once data is received i wanted to open Home Activity
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });

        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "id, first_name, last_name, email,gender, birthday, location");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();
    } else {
        Log.v("MyApp", getClass().toString() + "updateWithToken:Else(Token Null)");
    }
}//updatewithtoken
```

Also Override OnActivityResult as

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.v("MyApp", getClass().toString() + " Request:" + requestCode + " Result:" + resultCode);
    if (requestCode==64206) {
        Log.v("MyApp", getClass().toString() + " onActivityResult:If Facebook");
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

I used log to find request code is 64206 for facebook login.

Answer (score 0):

Please change here in the code of LoginButton.java class of facebook SDK

```
protected void configureButton(
        final Context context,
        final AttributeSet attrs,
        final int defStyleAttr,
        final int defStyleRes) {
    super.configureButton(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    setInternalOnClickListener(new LoginClickListener());

    parseLoginButtonAttributes(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);

    if (isInEditMode()) {
        // cannot use a drawable in edit mode, so setting the background color instead
        // of a background resource.
        setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.com_facebook_blue));
        // hardcoding in edit mode as getResources().getString() doesn't seem to work in
        // IntelliJ
        loginText = "Facebook";
    } else {
        accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(
                    AccessToken oldAccessToken,
                    AccessToken currentAccessToken) {
                setButtonText();
            }
        };
    }

    setButtonText();
}
```

Comment: i tried it, but LoginButton.java class is locked. I cannot edit it. Please tell me how to unlock it.

Comment: Go to Facebook sdk java folder and open LoginButton.java class and change  setButtonText(); method .