# Customize Facebook API login button

Tags: xml, facebook, api, android-studio

I've just started developing a new Android application  and integrated the Facebook API, my login looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCHh4.png

How can I customize the button of Facebook's login to look like my "Ingresar" button? (Size and font-family)

EDIT: This is the XML of the button, I took it from:
[Facebook for Developers Guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/)

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
android:id="@+id/login_button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" /> 

<!-- Ingresar button -->  

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
android:id="@+id/btn_login"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/button_marginBottom"
android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/button_marginTop"
android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
android:padding="@dimen/button_padding"
android:text="@string/btnLogin_text"
android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
```

Thank you in advance...

Comment: Hi could you post the xml of the facebook login button, thanks

Comment: @BrianSmith I've edited the question, regards

Comment: Thanks, could you also post the xml of the Ingresar button that way we can use the same styles specified on it in the facebook button

Comment: @BrianSmith done! by the way... I tried adding the padding style, even the android:text tag but it doesn't seems to work

Comment: not sure how do this if adding styling to button does not work however here is a good answer you could try http://stackoverflow.com/a/19179856/6144192

Comment: Worked pretty well, except for " fb:login_text="@string/loginFacebookButton"
fb:logout_text="" ", won't build with that lines

Comment: Try removing fb:logout_text="" and instead of using fb:login_text="@string/loginFacebookButton" just use fb:login_text="Login With Facebook"