# How to set standard Facebook login button apperancce on Android?

Tags: android, facebook

Does anyone know how to restore the standard facebook button appearance ?

My code:

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
            android:id="@+id/lpFacebookLoginButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="14dp"
            android:paddingBottom="14dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/small_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/small_vertical_margin"/>
```

and how it looks now :
[image]

it should look like this :[image]

how Facebook SDK is added in gradle:

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:latest.release'
```

Comment: You can customize the button. Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16314651/9652621) question